# How do I get Textmate to use MacRuby?

Tags: textmate, macruby

So, how do I get Textmate to use MacRuby, a branch of 1.9.2, instead of the default Ruby in OSX, 1.8.7?

Comment: I would strongly recommend that you pull the answer out of your question, simplify the question, and then answer your own question. I will vote up both your question and answer. By the way, great job of nailing this one!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Been working on this since last night…finally got it to work

How to Get MacRuby Running on TextMate

By (johnrubythecat*)

*reference to john robie, "the cat", thief played by cary grant in To Catch A Thief

Ruby on OS X is currently 1.8.7
But latest version of Ruby is 1.9.2 (MUCH faster)
And MacRuby (much better than RubyCocoa) is built on 1.9.2

- http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/
- http://www.macruby.org/
- http://rubycocoa.sourceforge.net/HomePage (obsolete, but if you're curious)

So here are instructions for easily building mac desktop apps using ruby

### INSTALL RVM

1) [install rvm](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/) with git

```
$ bash < <( curl http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/releases/rvm-install-head ) http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/
```

1.2) source command in .bash_profile or .bashrc (so rvm bin can be found):
`source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm`

### INSTALL MACRUBY

2) Use rvm to install MacRuby

```
rvm notes # to see available rubies
rvm install macruby-0.8 # for exmpl
```

3) then, `rvm --default macruby-0.8`
(or at least `rvm use macrmacruby-0.8`)

### CONFIGURE TEXTMATE

4) update Textmate bundles with this script, just to make sure you're up to date; see:

- http://www.christopherirish.com/2010/06/28/how-to-setup-textmate-to-use-rvm/
- and https://gist.github.com/455521

---

```
--- #!/usr/bin/env bash
mkdir -p /Library/Application\ Support/TextMate/
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /Library/Application\ Support/TextMate
cd /Library/Application\ Support/TextMate/
if [[ -d Bundles/.svn ]] ; then
  cd Bundles && svn up
else
  if [[ -d Bundles ]] ; then
    mv Bundles Bundles.old
  fi
  svn co http://svn.textmate.org/trunk/Bundles
fi
exit 0
```

---

5) Generate Ruby wrapper wrapper for TextMate
`rvm wrapper macruby-0.8 textmate`

wrapper is in `$HOME/.rvm/bin`; it's called `textmate_ruby`

6) go to shell variables in TextMate preferences and set `TM_RUBY` to
`/Users/homedirname/.rvm/bin/textmate_ruby`

that should do it

### RUN YOUR APP

7) this script ran great —opens a Cocoa window

```
framework 'AppKit'
class AppDelegate
  def applicationDidFinishLaunching(notification)
    voice_type = "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.GoodNews"
    @voice = NSSpeechSynthesizer.alloc.initWithVoice(voice_type)
  end

  def windowWillClose(notification)
    puts "Bye!"
    exit
  end

  def say_hello(sender)
    @voice.startSpeakingString("Hello World!")
    puts "Hello World!"
  end
end

app = NSApplication.sharedApplication
app.delegate = AppDelegate.new

window = NSWindow.alloc.initWithContentRect([200, 300, 300, 100],
  styleMask:NSTitledWindowMask|NSClosableWindowMask|NSMiniaturizableWindowMask,
  backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered, 
  defer:false)
window.title      = 'MacRuby: The Definitive Guide'
window.level      =  NSModalPanelWindowLevel
window.delegate   = app.delegate
button = NSButton.alloc.initWithFrame([80, 10, 120, 80])
button.bezelStyle = 4
button.title      = 'Hello World!'
button.target     = app.delegate
button.action     = 'say_hello:'
window.contentView.addSubview(button)
window.display
window.orderFrontRegardless
app.run
```

---

And here is a video discussing how to integrate MacRuby with XCode.

http://thinkcode.tv/catalog/introduction-macruby/

It's 8.99, but I am recommending something I purchased myself. It's MacRuby is out of date (0.6), but it shows the nuts and bolts of using MacRuby in XCode, including setting up the XIB and making connections, creating the application delegate, setting up Textmate as your external editor.

Quite useful. Recommended.

Comment: Nice work, and thanks for sharing! You can accept your own answer in 2 days.

Comment: Excellent answer! I will be voting it up as soon as my votes refresh!

Comment: and your next step is probably to install HotCocoa http://www.macruby.org/trac/wiki/HotCocoa

Comment: useful on first HotCocoa app -- http://stufftohelpyouout.blogspot.com/2010/02/create-macruby-hotcocoa-app.html

Answer (score 5):

Simpler answers:

1. Install [MacRuby](http://www.macruby.org/)
2. Go to TextMate->Preferences->Advanced->Shell Variables and add a variable named `TM_RUBY` set to `/usr/local/bin/macruby`.

   - Alternatively, edit the `PATH` variable to include `/usr/local/bin/` and just set `TM_RUBY` to `macruby`.

---

If you have installed MacRuby through [RVM](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/), then instead:

1. Generate stable wrapper:
   `rvm wrapper macruby-0.8 macruby` # creates ~/.rvm/bin/macruby
2. Set `TM_RUBY` to `/Users/yourusername/.rvm/bin/macruby` (must be the absolute path).

   - Alternatively, edit the `PATH` variable to include `/Users/yourusername/.rvm/bin` and just set `TM_RUBY` to `macruby`.

---

In case it wasn't obvious from the UI, you can use the checkbox next to `TM_RUBY` to enable or disable its use in TextMate.