# Could not find RubyGem haml

Tags: ruby, rubygems, textmate, haml

Using a fresh install of Ruby 1.9.2 (via RVM), Textmate, and the Handcrafted Haml bundle, I get the following error when trying to use it:

> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:827:in
>   report_activate_error': Could not find
>   RubyGem haml (>= 0) (Gem::LoadError)
>   from
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:261:inactivate'
>   from
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:68:in `gem' from -e:1

I ran sudo gem install haml and it installed successfully. The output of ruby -v is 1.9.2p180. It seems like TextMate is still looking for my system (Mac OS X) version of Ruby, not the new one (1.9.2) I installed. When I look at the gemsets for my RVM-managed Ruby 1.9.2 installation, the Haml gem is loaded. Any thoughts on how to get TextMate to search for the gem in my new/correct gemset?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to tell TextMate which Ruby to use. As you guessed and can see from the error, the PATH for TextMate causes it to use `/usr/bin/ruby`. See these questions and their answers:

- [How do I get Textmate to use MacRuby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909335/how-do-i-get-textmate-to-use-macruby/4909776#4909776)
- [TextMate, rvm and TM_RUBY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317933/textmate-rvm-and-tm-ruby)
- [Using RVM with different gemsets in TextMate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948915/using-rvm-with-different-gemsets-in-textmate)

I personally use my own non-RVM hand-compiled Ruby in `/usr/local/bin` and so I go into
`TextMate->Preferences->Advanced->Shell Variables`
and create a variable named `PATH` that is set to
`/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

*Note that I've put `/usr/local/bin` before `/usr/bin` so that my `ruby` is found before the system's.*